# Add recipient list in EXM programmatically - Sitecore 9.1.1

Tags: sitecore-api, exm

I was looking for how to add a list to the ***Included Recipient List*** section to an EXM **MessageItem** programmatically.

In **Sitecore 8.2** you could do

> MessageItem.RecipientManager.AddIncludedRecipientListId()

Anyone have an idea how to achieve this in the updated API in **Sitecore 9.1.1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code would help you:

```
using System;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign;
using Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Factories;
using Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Messages;
using Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Services;

namespace Demo
{
    public class CustomExmManager
    {
        private readonly IRecipientManagerFactory _recipientManagerFactory;
        private readonly IExmCampaignService _exmCampaignService;

        public CustomExmManager(IRecipientManagerFactory recipientManagerFactory, IExmCampaignService exmCampaignService)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)recipientManagerFactory, nameof(recipientManagerFactory));
            this._recipientManagerFactory = recipientManagerFactory;
            this._exmCampaignService = exmCampaignService;
        }

        public bool AddIncludedRecipientList(Guid recipientListId, Guid messageId)
        {
            MessageItem messageItem = this._exmCampaignService.GetMessageItem(messageId);
            return AddIncludedRecipientList(recipientListId, messageItem);
        }

        public bool AddIncludedRecipientList(Guid recipientListId, MessageItem messageItem)
        {
            IRecipientManager recipientManager = this._recipientManagerFactory.GetRecipientManager(messageItem);
            return recipientManager.AddIncludedRecipientListId(recipientListId);
        }
    }
}
```

If you already have an `MessageItem` object, you can remove the part where I initializes it by messageId using`_exmCampaignService`.

Comment: Is the IRecipientManagerFactory from dependencyInjection or where does it come from?

Comment: @FilipJönsson From dependencyInjection. It should be there already.

Comment: @FilipJönsson has it helped?

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you!